# processing text file with locale, ignore non-Ascii characters

Tags: haskell

How can I load and print the content of this file?
http://daiw.de/share/misc/2014-05-28_haskell/foo.txt

```
nice text: lalala.
mean german text: Größe!
```

My current example code

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    content <- readFile "foo.txt"
    putStrLn content
```

produces the following output:

```
nice text: lalala.
Main.hs: foo.txt: hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)
```

It would be totally OK if all non-Ascii characters would be replaced by a dummy character or dropped completely.

Answer (score 3):

GHC supports the native locale. As long as your local setting is something sensible, it will "just work":

```
$ runhaskell foo.hs
nice text: lalala.
mean german text: Größe!
```

Set e.g.

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Ok. And is there also a possibility to filter out these characters in case I do not know in advance what locale to expect in the input file?

Comment: A good option is to assume utf8, then use the text and text-icu packages to do the right thing with the encodings.

Comment: The files I have here unfortunately are not utf8.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrote this and it works for me right now:

```
import Data.Char
import Control.Applicative
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B

readFileAscii :: String -> IO String
readFileAscii path = B.unpack <$> B.map (clearChar '-') <$> B.readFile path
    where
        clearChar :: Char -> Char -> Char
        clearChar d c
            | c == '\r' || c == '\n' = c
            | c >= '\32' && c < '\128' = c
            | otherwise = d

main :: IO ()
main = do
    content <- readFileAscii "foo.txt"
    putStrLn $ content
    putStrLn $ map toUpper content
```

I hope it is not an unclean solution and will haunt me later. If it is bad, please let me know. As you probably already noticed, I am a beginner regarding Haskell.

Comment: I would just preserve any char < 128, and replace everything else. This should work with utf-8, ISO-8859-*, and some other single-byte encodings. A more robust approach could be to use some heuristics to guess the encoding beforehand.